# javafx Button wrapper: Provide callers with action events?

Tags: java, events, javafx

I would like my class to be one which fires an action the same way that a button does (but I'm containing the button in my class).  I am wondering how to do this, and if this breaks Java rules to do so?

What would I have to do to make `ValueButton` a type that one can receive action events from (when the button is clicked), and receive a reference to the `ValueButton` object which originated the event?

```
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class ValueButton {

    Button button;
    int val;

    /** Use string of value for string */
    public ValueButton(int val) {
        init(val, null);
    }
    /** Provide value and string explicity */
    public ValueButton(int val, String str) {
        init(val, str);
    }
    private void init(int val, String str) {
        this.val = val;
        if(str == null) 
            str = Integer.toString(val);
        button = new Button(str);
        button.setOnAction((ae) -> {
            // I would like to pass *this* along to caller/user of ValueButton
        });
    }

    int getValue() { return val; }
    String getString() { return button.getText(); }
}
```

Comment: Why not use the regular `Button` and `setUserData`?

Comment: How do you expect a class not subclassing any UI-based classes to be rendered on the screen? If it is not on the screen, how would you use your mouse to click onto it? You are likely to end up using regular `Button` or subclass that or another similar class.

Comment: In addition to above, I was thinking of subclassing `ValueButton` with one that adds another `String` value to it.  The caller also may be a caller of a `NumberPad`, which contains a list of `ValueButton`-type objects, and I thought maybe I could pass the event back to the original caller, but, I wanted to have a queriable object passed back to the event handler along with it.